# Setting different keys in Bridge/pivot table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have inherited a rails application however the tables aren't using the standard rails foreign keys. My question is, how do I modify foreign keys in the bridge table in Rails.

*These are the tables:*

```
Sharedboardonforums{id, board, name, path}

Categories{id, name, cached_slug, category_type}

Sharedboardonforums_categories{id, shared, category}
```

The `Sharedboardonforums_categories` is the bridge/pivot table between Sharedboardonforums and Categories. `shared` is for `Sharedboardonforums` and `category` is for `Categories`.

How do I set the foriegn key for Rails to recognize the `shared` and `category` as the keys for Sharedboardonforums and Categories?

`Version Rails 2.3.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the relationship with a combination of `has_many` and `belongs_to`. I added `:foreign_key` to attributes